# TestNG: Should running tests by tests by method or class call the @BeforeSuite method?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a suite of tests that has a setUp method annotated with @BeforeSuite which runs before the suite. Occasionally I will need to run tests individually or all tests in a class. Is there a way to get my setUp method to run before these too.

My understanding is that TestNG creates a default suite so it shouldn't matter how I run the tests, if I have a method annotated with @BeforeSuite it should run before all tests. However this doesn't work for me. It runs only when I run the full suite.

xml suite. If I run a test from here it works. (right-click, select run)

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="OvernightSuite">
<test name="Test Sequential" preserve-order="true" parallel="none">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.myComp.test.cases.setUpClass" />
        <class name="com.com.myComp.test.cases.testClass1" />
        <class name="com.com.myComp.test.cases.testClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Set-up class

```
public class setUpClass{
@BeforeSuite
public void setUp() {
    populateDataSources();
    populateVariables();
}
    @Test
    public void datasourcesWereSetUpTest() {
        boolean result = method.read();
        assert(result);
    }
}
```

One of the test classes. If I run here, (highlight, right-click, select run) the beforeSuite is not executed.

```
public class testClass1{
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        boolean result = method.read();
        assert(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `@BeforeSuite` annotated method is part of the test class (the one that has one or more `@Test` methods in it), it should work without you having to do anything extra.

But if your `@BeforeSuite` method is in a different class, then the only way of you having it executed is if you do one of the following :

- Create a suite xml file, that includes the class which contains the `@BeforeSuite` method, along with your test class. (or)
- Create a TestNG listener which implements the interface `org.testng.ISuiteListener` and move the logic of `@BeforeSuite` into `onStart()`, and then wire in this listener via the `@Listeners` annotation (or) `<listeners>` tag (or) via the Service Loader approach. For more information, you can read [this](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/listen-to-what-i-have-to-say-about-testng-listeners/) blog post of mine.

Comment: Using the suggested method above adding an xml suite which includes the setup class works if I run by selecting a test class from within the xml suite, but not if I run from the actual method in the class itself. Any suggestions as to why? Should this work at all? Is it maybe to do with my IDE setup?

Comment: I didnt quite get your question. Can you please share a screenshot of how you are running your test from within the IDE and also show the code which contains your test class and your `@BeforeSuite` annotated method ?

Comment: @ciffieM - Like I stated in my answer, if you try and run `testClass1` by right clicking it from an IDE, only that class will be chosen to run. Your `setup()` resides in a different class and so it will not be executed. You would need to following one of the two options that I mentioned in my response.

Comment: So if I - Create a suite xml file, that includes the class which contains the @BeforeSuite method, along with your test class.

Thats what i have done. See the xml file above

Comment: Yes that suite xml should run your `@BeforeSuite` annotated method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any of the following options:

```
'@BeforeTest'
```

To execute a set-up method before any of the test methods included in the < test > tag in the testng.xml file.

```
'@BeforeMethod'
```

To execute a set-up method before any of the test methods annotated as @Test.

http://howtesting.blogspot.ie/2012/12/difference-between-beforetest-and.html

Comment: Yes, @BeforeTest should work here too, it has the same result. It runs from a test class called from the .xml file but not before a test called in java class